# Azure Devops set Due Date by an rule

Tags: azure-devops

I'm try to add an rule in Azure DevOps so that when someone set an Severity, it automatically set the due date according to that Severity. Like this:

[image: Rule screen like i want to add]

So the key is to get the date set based on today's date and then add a couple of days. When i try to do it with @Today (what is used in queries) I get an exception:

> VS402809: @Today + 28 is an invalid value for field type DateTime. Change the field value and try again.

Someone an idea how to set this rule so it works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Azure DevOps does not support operation like your. Check this plugin: [Work item form one click actions](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=mohitbagra.witoneclickactions).
It contains similar operation:

> @Today Macro
>
> This macro sets the value to the current date. This can
> only be used in "Set Field value" action. Users can also choose to
> add/subtract certain number of days from @today by using "@today-2" or
> "@today+3"

Or you can write custom application through [REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1) to update the date with 2 operations:

1. Query work items without due date
2. Update due date

Comment: Thanks you for your answer. The REST API made me think i could do this with an Azure Logic App. That was very easy. The result is two Logic Apps, one when an item is created and one when an item is updated.

Answer (score 1):

Because of the answer Shamrai Aleksander as given I was thinking how to use the REST API of DevOps without coding. That became Azure Logic Apps.

I've created on when an item is created and one when the item is updated. They both look like this:

[image: Logic app steps]

So i get an update when a work item is created, then I Initialize the variable days with an default value of 0. Then i switch on the value Severity (that you get from When a work item is created) and based on that value I set the correct amount of days in the Days Variable. Then I update the work item where I set the due date to add the days we just set to the created date. That is the following expression:

```
addDays(triggerBody()?['fields']?['System_CreatedDate'], variables('Days'))
```

This works like a charm for me and is easy to adjust if the days need to be changed.