# "Resolved Date" how is it being set in Azure DevOps

Tags: azure-devops

We do not have the standard workflow and therefore, I am not sure how is this field being set. Any advice? I checked the provided documentation, but as we do not have a state "resolved" or "fixed", not sure how is it working. Thanks

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/queries/query-by-workflow-changes?view=azure-devops#activated-bydate-and-resolved-bydate-fields

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Could you please [edit] the post to contain a [mre]? That way, we can see what makes your case non-standard.

Comment: Hi @Ilvija, Have you got a chance to check the answer below? Hope the information would help address your concerns.

Comment: HI @Ilvija, I have updated my answer with a sample, hope it will help understand how these fields are updated. If the answer could address your concerns, you may consider marking it, which may help others with similar queries. Thx.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your description, it seems that your work items of your process don't have the expected states `resolved` or `fixed`.

To customize the work tracking system, we need **first** to [create an inherited process](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/settings/work/manage-process?view=azure-devops) through the administrative user interface for the organization. And you can configure the project(s) to use this process.

Within this inherited process, you can not only [create new work item types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/settings/work/customize-process-work-item-type?view=azure-devops) but also enrich the work items with custom [states](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/settings/work/customize-process-workflow?view=azure-devops#add-a-workflow-state) or [fields](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/settings/work/add-custom-field?view=azure-devops).

By default a `task` work item of `Agile` does not have the `Resolved` **state** under the `Resolve` **category**; nor it has the fields of `Resolved Reason` `Resolved By` or `Resolved Date` (These fields are existing fields not custom fields).

However, with the help of an inherited process based on the default process, we can add the state and fields for the `task` work item.

Taking my demo below for example, I have created the inherited process `AgileInherited`. For the `task` work item type in this process, I added custom state `Pending Response` under the **In Progress** category and custom state `Mitigated` under the **Resolved** category. I also added the existing fields `Activated By` `Activated Date` `Resolved Reason` `Resolved By` and `Resolved Date` for `task`.

[image]

Once the task state is changed to the `Pending Response` by a user, the `Activated By` field will be automatically populated with this user identity; and as soon as the modification is **saved**, the `Activated Date` is updated;

[image]

Similarly, once the task state is changed to `Mitigated` by a user, the `Resolved By` field will be automatically populated with this user identity; and as soon as the modification is **saved**, the `Resolved Date` is updated;

Here is the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/settings/work/customize-process-workflow?view=azure-devops#add-states) for your reference to customize the workflow and hope the information would help understand the machenism.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not have the Resolved state... Why do you need this field? This is a system field. You can not replicate its behavior in a custom process because there is a restriction for the date-time fields on the work item rules: [How to use dates in Work Item rules?](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/how-to-use-dates-in-work-item-rules/670257)

If you want to create something similar, check this question: [Azure Devops set Due Date by an rule](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62282586/azure-devops-set-due-date-by-an-rule)

Comment: I was more curious to understand how it works, considering that we do not have the standard workflow but the field gets populated